# Network problem with a dual boot system

Tags: networking, 20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 together with Windows 10 in Dual boot.

Lately I started having a network problem.

I searched a lot for an answer but didn't find any solution that worked perfectly for me.
In a nutshell, when I go into Windows and I have internet, if I go back to Ubuntu, it say "Wired Connected" but I can't go into any website, and pinging gives a HUGE packet loss (above 80%).
after a few reboots, I got my internet working on Ubuntu, but now I don't have internet on Windows, and it keeps changing around.

This started happening after we changed a router at home from a router via DSL line to a router via Cable. At windows I tried to reset the network adapter and it worked for a spell, but after several reboots (including into Ubuntu), again I have no internet on windows.
On Ubuntu I tried several things: switching off local detection of avahi daemon, restart of NetworkManager and changing /etc/resolv.conf to default (make the system regenerate the file).
I'm not certain that the problem is concerned with IP address so I didn't try switching from DHCP to static IP.

My theory is that once one OS is using the network card, it is locked with that OS for a certain period.

Is there any chance to make it so either Ubuntu or Windows will unlock the card when I reboot between the different OS's? I think it's a driver issue, but I'm not certain.

Here is the necessary network information:

**ifconfig**

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a00:a040:19a:3163:bcab:118e:a9b8:bfca  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::c2aa:642b:986:9e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a00:a040:19a:3163:7fbc:912b:4eb9:c1e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 0c:9d:92:80:7a:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5679  bytes 3537539 (3.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4933  bytes 1283158 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 902  bytes 80789 (80.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 902  bytes 80789 (80.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**lspci -knn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] [8086:3e1f] (rev 08)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 08)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a36d] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:a36f] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [1043:8694]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:a360] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller [8086:a352] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a33c] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 [8086:a33f] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a303] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8694]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [1043:86c7]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:a324] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [1043:8694]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] [10de:0622] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] [19da:1043]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

**ethtool enp3s0**

```
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

As you can see here, currently I'm at the state where Ubuntu has a splendid connection. Right now I have no connection in Win 10 (even though it says there as well that the wired connection is connected).

I'd appreciate any solution that will help my case.

Comment: Probably it's a hardware-level problem, either with a cable or with new router. Please clarify if you have several computers (or other similar devices, like smart TV or gaming console) connected to this router **via cable connection**? If so, do they have similar problems or not?

Comment: We have 3 computers connected to the router, and 1 smart TV (which we hardly use so no problem there). to clarify, The router is connected to the internet via cable, not the phone line. The other computer don't use dual OS systems and there are no problems there. Only my computer has dual boot system.

Comment: Your MTU is probably set wrong in your connection profile, or in your router. This occurred when switching from DSL to cable.

Comment: one small question - does changing the MTU value will affect greatly the speed of my connection?

Comment: I just tried that (first in the router settings, and then via sudo ifconfig enp3s0 mtu ...) but both didn't work. The first screwed the connection completely, to all the computers so I had to reset the router.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Realtek_8169_driver_problem I would try flipping the wake-on-lan setting in Windows first.

Comment: I recommend to check whether this problem is caused by cable or not: if possible, please  connect your computer through another working cable and test it for some reasonable time. You've mentioned ping - indeed, it's helpful in diagnostics - if you regularly see massive packet losses, it's usually caused by a damaged cable (should be re-crimped or replaced by a new one), or, less frequently, by faulty router or NIC (network interface controller). Sometimes packet losses are caused by software-level problems (quite rarely).

Comment: Hello to everyone who answered me.
As it currently stands, now I got the situation somewhat improved:
I have internet on Ubuntu, but now and then no internet on windows which I fix every time by enabling and disabling the Shutdown Wake On LAN feature. I installed the Realtek drivers for both Ubuntu and Windows. 
Any further suggestions as to how to deal with this thing?